# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type | Observable array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I retrieve an array of objects from the server and in my app I group this data by category to display the names and the types of each category.

```
http.get(url).map(res => res.json()).flatMap(array => array)
.groupBy(cat => cat.name)
.flatMap(cats => cats.reduce(acc, cat) => {
  cats.name = cat.name;
  cats.types.push(cat);
}, {types: []})
```

This takes data that looks like:

```
[{name: "ENTERTAINMENT", type: "BUSINESS"},
{name: "ENTERTAINMENT", type: "CHARITY"},
{name: "GAS" type: "TRANSPORTATION"}]
```

and transforms it into:

```
[{name: "ENTERTAINMENT", types: [{type: "BUSINESS"}, {type: "CHARITY"}],
{name: "GAS", types: [{type: "TRANSPORTATION"}]]
```

This is working fine. I want to iterate over the outer observable to display the name, then iterate over the types and display them, e.g.

```
<cats *ngFor="let cat of cats | async">
  {{cat.name}}
  <types *ngFor="let type of cat.types">{{type.type}}</types></cats>
```

When I do this, I get

> ```
> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'ENTERTAINMENT'.
> ```

I can get this to work fine if I just add `.toArray()` to the observable and remove the `async`, but I am trying to get this to work using observables.

I have also tried to use `trackBy` to check the name

```
*ngFor="let cat of (cats | async); trackBy cat?.name"
```

However I get the same error when I do this.

Is there any way for me to use the observable array of objects in `ngFor`?